# Multiple applications using the same application services

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnetdb

How can I have multiple applications, written for the same client sharing the same application services (is that the name of that database that holds membership?).

I'm thinking about creating an aspnetdb for each client and use it on every system they have. That way they can share users and other stuff.

Is that a correct way of thinking?

And by the way, there are some tables on that db that I have no idea what is used for. Can someone point some article explaining what those are for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think in terms of 1 to Many, 1 to 1 and etc.

Indeed in your case you can create 1 database to keep user accounts and share it between all applications and services.

Have a look there:

1) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405740.aspx

2) http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/neeraj/archive/2011/12/14/implement-windows-authentication-and-security-in-wcfservice.aspx

3) http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2010/03/22/a-simple-wcf-service-with-username-password-authentication-the-things-they-don-t-tell-you/

Answer (score 1):

If your application are desktop application, i recommend to use WCF (window communication foundation), otherwise web service is the simpler solution for web applications.
Notice that WCF can work in many protocol http, tcp...
WCF or web service should work on server side(where your data exists), it might be the computer where your client applications works

Here an example for WCF:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16765/WCF-Windows-Communication-Foundation-Example

Answer (score 1):

You can share Users and other stuff in the application services database.
The only thing you need to do is set the applicationName for the providers in the web.config/app.config to the same value

the other tables store profile and role information and webpart personalizion settings